# Show that $^{n+1}C_r= ^nC_r+^nC_{r-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

> Show that $^{n+1}C_r= ^nC_r+^nC_{r-1}$

$^nC_r=\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+1)}{r!}$

$^nC_{r-1}=\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+2)}{(r-1)!}$

$^nC_r+^nC_{r-1}=\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+1)}{r!}+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+2)r}{r(r-1)!}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{[n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+2)](n-r+1+r)}{r!}=\dfrac{(n+1)(n)(n-1)...(n-r+2)}{r!}$

This seems correct, but I'm a bit confused about $n-r+1$ and $n-r+2$, because I'm just plugging in $n-1$ for $n$ and $r-1$ for $r$, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing here.In essence I guess my plug and chug is correct, but I have no idea what it is I am doing and if someone can explain to me what these actions signify that would be great thank you.

Comment: What is this even asking? Is there some spiritual significance behind the algebra? No probably not.

Comment: @manlet_hunter,I think OP wants a Combinatorial argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine there are "$n+1$" students, out of which 1 of the students is disabled , you have to form a group of $r$ students

One way to think is to select $r$ students out of $n+1$ $$=\binom{n+1}{r}$$

Other way is to think in terms of Disabled person, There are only two ways to form group, Either The group has disabled person, Or the group doesn't have disabled person,

Case-$(1)$ -When the disabled person is in group, We then have to select $r-1$ players out of remaining $n$ players
$$=\binom {n}{r-1}$$

Case-$(2)$-When the disabled person is **not** in group, We then have to select $r$ players out of remaining $n$ players

$$=\binom {n}{r}$$

Total ways$$=\binom {n}{r-1}+\binom {n}{r}$$

As number of ways to form groups is same , even If we think differently

$$\binom{n+1}{r}=\binom {n}{r-1}+\binom {n}{r}$$

Must be true

Comment: The disabled person in this story story is an example of the approach common in combinatorial arguments and known as a *distinguished element*. One might instantiate the distinguished element as, say, one’s own daughter, or as the tallest in a group of people, or anything else similarly unique. My adviser used to call it the *weirdo*: there are $n -1 \choose r$ ways to form an $r$-person group happy not to have to cope with the weirdo and $n-1 \choose {r-1}$ ways to select the $r-1$ poor souls to round out the $r$-person group if the weirdo **is** the $r$th member.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum,That's a good Pedagogical choice to name the person a *weirdo*,It seems so relatable and funny...

Comment: I certainly found it so. And quite memorable.

Answer (score 0):

we have :$$^nC_r=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-r+1)}{r!}$$

therfore:
$$^nC_{r-1}+^nC_r=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1)!}+\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} \\ \frac{n!}{r!(n+1-r)!}\left({r+n-r+1}\right)=\frac{(n+1)!}{r!(n+1-r)!}=^{n+1}C_r$$